# Code First Migrations With Custom Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I'm using Code First Migrations with Entity Framework. I'm using a custom Constructor with a connectionstring that is specific for a certain user that's logged in on the application.

When de application loads I want the initialize the database with the user connectionstring and migrate it to the latest version if there are any changes in the database context. I'm using Structure map to inject the unit of work.

**Global Asax**

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddRegistry(new StandardRegistry());
            cfg.AddRegistry(new ControllerRegistry());
            cfg.AddRegistry(new ActionFilterRegistry(() => Container ?? ObjectFactory.Container));
            cfg.AddRegistry(new MvcRegistry());
            cfg.AddRegistry(new TaskRegistry());
            cfg.AddRegistry(new ModelMetadataRegistry());
        });
```

**StandardRegistry class**

```
 For<ICustomerUnitOfWork>().Use(new CustomerUnitOfWork(new CustomerContext()));
        For<CustomerContext>().Use(new CustomerContext());
```

At this point I don't know the connectionstring of the user because the user is not logged in. Problem when the model has changed, structuremap throws an exception because the context model has changed.

**Context**

```
private static string _connectionString;

    static CustomerContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<CustomerContext, Configuration>());
    }

    public CustomerContext()
        : base(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString) ? "FooDatabase" : _connectionString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
            Database.SetInitializer(new CustomerContextInitializer());
    }


    public CustomerContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
            Database.SetInitializer(new CustomerContextInitializer());
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
```

**CustomerContextInitializer**

```
 public class CustomerContextInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CustomerContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(CustomerContext context)
    {
        var informationService = new InformationService
        {
            ObjectState = ObjectState.Added,
            ConnectorClass =
                "Conexio.InformationService.Contracts.IInformationService, Conexio.InformationService.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
            DisplayName = "IInformationService"
        };
```

Is there a way to add the rules to the standardRegistry class in runtime to invoke the constructur with the connectionstring ? Or is there another way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, your best way to approach this is by creating a factory class that's responsible for creating your instance of `ICustomerUnitOfWork` at runtime which can then be configured in your StructureMap registry like so:

```
this.For<ICustomerUnitOfWork>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<YourFactoryClass>().ResolveCustomerUnitOfWork());
```

Your `ICustomerUnitOfWork` will then resolve to your factory class that can have its own set of dependencies injected into it to determined what the correct context is.

```
public interface ICustomerUnitOfWork
{

}

public class YourFactoryClass
{
    public YourFactoryClass(string connectionString)
    {

    }

    public ICustomerUnitOfWork ResolveCustomerUnitOfWork()
    {
        // Perform runtime configuration

        return unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!